# Transform every visible cell on different angle

Tags: ios, swift, nsindexpath

I want to Transform every visible cell on different angle in my collection view, i tried to use index to do it but the result pretty random, and when i scroll it mess up

```
override func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
var identy = CATransform3DIdentity
identy.m34 = -1/200

let arrayOfAngles = [-0.4, -0.2, 2, 4]
//    for index in currentIndexPath {
for (index, cell) in collectionView!.visibleCells().enumerate() {
  let angle:CGFloat!
  print(index)
  switch(index) {
  case 0: angle = 0.2
  case 1: angle = 0.1
  case 2: angle = -0.1
  case 3: angle = 0.4
  case 4: angle = 0.4
  case 5: angle = 0.4
  case 6: angle = -0.4
  case 7: angle = 0.2
  case 8: angle = 0.0
  case 9: angle = 0.0
  case 10: angle = -0.2
  case 11: angle = -0.3
  default: angle = 10
  }

  UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: { () -> Void in
    cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(identy, angle,  5,  90,  0 )
    }, completion: nil)
}




}
```

Comment: what do you mean on a different angle? do you mean when the user tilts the screen?

Comment: nope, just when user scroll the items are rotating

Comment: Something similar to cylinder in https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel ?

Comment: @AdamTucholski Yes! Thanks